# "Step it out" - WhatDdoes It Mean?

Tags: american-english

I was watching Death Wish starring Charles Bronson, and one of the characters says this (adding context): "Based on the figures, I don't see how Blueridge can underwrite 50% percent. Jainchill has been very successful in a small way."

Charles Bronson's character replies: "I suggest you send a man down from our San Francisco office to step it out... redesign it if necessary."

What does "step it out" mean in this context?

Comment: I removed some apparently irrelevant lines "because that's a high rise/ for the acreage involved".  I don't think you intended to include them

Comment: Perhaps the idea is to step out (measure) the area/acreage.